# Membership API redirects me to login page after successful authentication

Tags: redirect, asp.net-membership

I'm using Membership API with forms authentication.
Sometimes, when a user try to go to login.aspx page (for example 
`www.mysite.com/login.aspx`), there is a redirect event happening and the address bar shows something like this `www.mysite.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=Login.aspx`

I'm like to draw attention to that: User enter his login and password and then he will be redirected to a login page again.

I have tried to reproduce this bug under my debug session, but I couldn't.

Tell me please why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Are you having roles problems? Does the user have access to the return URL page?

Without more information, I can't really suggest any answers, but you might find [SO:62013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013/problem-with-login-control-of-asp-net) or [Forums:1318557](http://forums.asp.net/p/1318557/2620196.aspx) or [this blog post](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=55) helpful.

If not, take a look in your [Trace log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfbfw58f(v=VS.85).aspx) and see if you're ever getting to your return URL. In the problem I'm having at the moment I can see:

```
19   9/7/2010 5:50:03 PM   /login.aspx     302   POST   View Details
20   9/7/2010 5:50:03 PM   /Default.aspx   302   GET    View Details
21   9/7/2010 5:50:03 PM   /login.aspx     200   GET    View Details
```

so I'm getting a successful login, but my return URL is redirecting back to the login.  (I'm about to raise this as a question on here myself).

But my first guess would be to look at roles. Can you edit the question to add in the appropriate section of your web.config (and remember to remove any sensitive data first ;o)